# Uniqueness constraint in union of two columns' values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, unique-constraint

Using postgresql 9.5, assume I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
 id INT,
 primary TEXT,
 secondary TEXT
)
```

I want to guarantee that the union of values in `primary` and `secondary` does not contain duplicates. Is this doable via index/checks or do I have to go to a trigger?

For example,

```
INSERT INTO t(id, primary, secondary) VALUES(1, 'a', 'b');
INSERT INTO t(id, primary, secondary) VALUES(1, 'x', 'y');
INSERT INTO t(id, primary, secondary) VALUES(1, 'a', 'z');
INSERT INTO t(id, primary, secondary) VALUES(1, 'z', 'a');
```

The latter two INSERTs should fail.

Comment: Uhm, isn't that just displacing the problem? Now I have to make sure I don't improperly link the values.

Comment: Please clarify: should `(a,b)` and `(a,z)` be allowed together or not?

Comment: To simplify, if you only have {1,'a','b'} in the table, you should not be able to insert {1,'a','t'}, {1,'t','a'}, {1,'b','t'}, {1,'t','b'}. The `id` column is irrelevant.

Comment: I think this would be possible with an exclusion constraint if there was an access method for arrays  `exclude using gist ( (array["primary", secondary]) with &&)` - but unfortunately there is no access method for that.

Answer (score 3):

A trigger solution might work but I'd prefer to normalize the design and have simple constraints:

The table that is now:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 t_primary TEXT,
 t_secondary TEXT
) ;
```

would become:

```
CREATE TABLE tt (
 id INT,
 t_no SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 t_text TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, t_no)
 UNIQUE (t_text),
 CHECK (t_no IN (1,2))
) ;
```

Then your inserts

```
INSERT INTO t (id, t_primary, t_secondary) VALUES (1, 'a', 'b');
INSERT INTO t (id, t_primary, t_secondary) VALUES (2, 'x', 'y');
INSERT INTO t (id, t_primary, t_secondary) VALUES (3, 'a', 'z');
INSERT INTO t (id, t_primary, t_secondary) VALUES (4, 'z', 'a');
```

would become:

```
INSERT INTO tt (id, t_no, t_text) VALUES (1, 1, 'a'), (1, 2, 'b');
INSERT INTO tt (id, t_no, t_text) VALUES (2, 1, 'x'), (2, 2, 'y');
INSERT INTO tt (id, t_no, t_text) VALUES (3, 1, 'a'), (3, 2, 'z');  -- will fail
INSERT INTO tt (id, t_no, t_text) VALUES (4, 1, 'z'), (4, 2, 'a');  -- will fail
```

Finally you can have the original output with:

```
CREATE VIEW t AS
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.t_text as t_primary,
    b.t_text as t_secondary,
FROM tt AS a
  JOIN tt AS b
    ON a.id = b.id AND a.t_no = 1 AND b.t_no = 2 ;

SELECT *
FROM t ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution is to create unique indexes as:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    x int,
    y int
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X1 ON T (LEAST(x, y));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X2 ON T (GREATEST(x, y));
```

But as @alphadogg points out, this will fail in the following situation:

```
INSERT INTO t(x,y) VALUES (1,3); 
INSERT INTO t(x,y) VALUES (0,1);
```

1<3 and 1>0, so these tuples will not violate the unique indexes.

A kludge (that probably will perform badly for heavy modification of the table) is:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V(x) as 
    select x from t 
    union all 
    select y from t 
with data;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X1 ON V(x);

create or replace function refresh_mat_view()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    refresh materialized view v; --
    return null; --
end $$;

create trigger refresh_mat_view
after insert or update on t 
for each row
    execute procedure refresh_mat_view();
```

Whenever a row is inserted or updated in t, x union all y is checked for uniqueness.

Test in sqlfiddle for PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
INSERT INTO t(x,y) VALUES (1,3), (0,1);
ERROR: could not create unique index "x1" Detail: Key (x)=(1) is duplicated. Where: SQL statement "refresh materialized view
```

I'm no expert in PostgreSQL but I assume this is going to be very expensive for a large table with massive modifications.

Another option is to have an before trigger that checks for existence of new x and y in table, and raises an exception if found (I assume this is what @ypercubeᵀᴹ refers to at the beginning of his post). Personally I find triggers to be rather awkward in PostgreSQL so I won't try to create one (I'm rather surprised that I managed to create one above :-).

Comment: Doesn't work. `INSERT INTO t(id,p,s) VALUES (1,'a','b');` then `INSERT INTO t(id,p,s) VALUES (1,'t','b');` was allowed. After first insert, X1 contains 'a' and X2 contains 'b'. The second insert asks i X1 could contain 'b', which it can, and if X2 can contain 't', which it can. Thus allowing an unwanted record.

Comment: I understand that it could be done by normalizing, but wanted to know i I could do it without incurring join.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll see if I can come up with an alternative approach or remove my answer.